# Cannot read files from resources folder

Tags: java, file, path, resources, embedded-resource

**Final edit:** now the code looks like this

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/static/master-key.txt");
String masterKey = null;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
masterKey = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("the master key is " + masterKey);
```

**Original post**

I have a problem when reading txt file from `resources` folder.

This what project structure looks like:
[projStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVs2c.png)

When I invoke the following code

```
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("static/master-key.txt").getPath());
File mkFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("static/master-key.txt").getPath());
```

this what happens

```
/D:/Dropbox/Coding/Intellij%20IDEA/TishenkoKPO/target/classes/static/master-key.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
D:\Dropbox\Coding\Intellij%20IDEA\TishenkoKPO\target\classes\static\master-key.txt (System cannot find the specified path)
```

I've googled alot but have no clue of why this happens

**Edit 1**:
Part of the code rebuilt as community suggested (working with file as a resource)

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("static/master-key.txt");
String masterKey = null;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
masterKey = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("the master key is " + masterKey); //successfuly outputs the first line if exists
```

**Edit 2:** resourcepath should begin with `/`

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/static/master-key.txt");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("static/master-key.txt");
```

This is searching for a resource relative to the package / directory of the class that is calling it. It is likely that resource can actually be found **relative to the root of the application structure.** To do that, add a leading `/`, like this.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/static/master-key.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getResource("resources\static\master-key.txt").getPath());
```

and if u targeting a path use '\' not '/'.
And u can try

```
YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("resources\static\master-key.txt");
```

or

```
YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("static\master-key.txt");
```

Comment: That's weird. I've tried everything you've mentioned but nothing works. It throws Nullpointerexception as if there's no file by that filepath.

Comment: You have file in this path ? D:\Dropbox\Coding\Intellij%20IDEA\TishenkoKPO\target\classes\static\master-key.txt

Comment: Indeed, I have. Could it be that 'space' in the name of a folder causing the problem? Java interprets 'space' as '%20'

Comment: Edit: no, that's not the case. Have just tested that on a brand new project, works fine. Maybe the problem lays in the location of the class which method I invoke.